# Game Maker:DoAdd:2:undefined value

Tags: undefined, game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

Code in Step:

```
If (keyboard_check(ord("W"))) {   phy_position_y -= 4;
}
If (keyboard_check(ord("A"))) {   phy_position_x -= 4; 
}
If (keyboard_check(ord("S"))) {   phy_position_y += 4;
}
If (keyboard_check(ord("D"))) {   phy_position_x += 4;
}
```

Pressing any of the WASD keys produces the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `phy_position_y` and `phy_position_x` have been initialised before.

It tries to add 4 to it's value, but it can't do that because it doesn't know it's own value. (Even if it's 0, you should initialise it with 0)

So for example, you can put this in your Create Event:

```
phy_position_x = 0;
phy_position_y = 0;
```

Alternatively, assuming you'll decide the objects current position, you can also use the build-in variables `x` and `y`:

```
If (keyboard_check(ord("W"))) {   y -= 4;
}
If (keyboard_check(ord("A"))) {   x -= 4; 
}
If (keyboard_check(ord("S"))) {   y += 4;
}
If (keyboard_check(ord("D"))) {   x += 4;
}
```

I think eventually, you'll need to define the `x` and `y` anyways if you want to move your object, but understanding custom variables and the need to define them first is a key.

Answer (score 0):

`phy_position_x` and `phy_position_y` can only be used if `Uses physics` flag is checked for the object. Either enable that, or use the regular `x` and `y` as Steven suggested.